# Vector only reads one line from .txt file c++

Tags: c++, file-io, vector, storing-data

Im trying to read data from a .txt file into a vector but it stops after storing the first line.

This is the data I'm reading from the file.

```
0 100 08 00 00
0,182,08 00 15
1,100,08 50 46
1,132,08 51 18
```

And this is the code

```
input.open ("RaceData.txt");
if (input.fail())
{
    cout <<"Cannot Open File.\n";
    exit(1);
}

int lap(0), racer(0), time(0);
vector <int> data;

while (input >> lap >> racer >> time)
{
   data.push_back(lap);
   data.push_back(racer);
   data.push_back(time);

}

//display
for (int i=0; i < data.size(); i++)
    cout << data [i] << " ";
```

I think it might not continue reading because of the commas if so, how do I not read the commas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You _want_ to read or, at least, skip the commas. That you are not extracting them _is_ the problem. I think you should read the whole line into a string then parse it in isolation.

Comment: Your file format doesn't seem to be consistent. Why does the first line not have any commas while all the following ones do? If you want to be able to parse a file that you read, you need it to have a consistent format.

Comment: @bku_drytt The example in the book in the book I'm using is vague. I used the data that was given, but I think it was meant to not have any commas because after I got rid of all the commas the data was stored in the vector just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to ignore the commas is to not ignore the whitespace. Here is an example:

```
...
char c;
input >> std::noskipws;
while (input >> lap >> c >> racer >> c >> time >> c)
{
...
```

Depending on how you expect the file format to be, you may need to alter the above to accept multple whitespaces. I hope this helps.